# How to compare filenames in two text files on Linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have two lists `list1` and `list2` with a filename on each line. I want a `result` with all filenames that are only in `list2` and not in `list1`, regardless of specific file extensions (but not all). Using Linux bash, any commands that do not require any extra installations. In the example lists, I do know all file extensions that I wish to ignore.  I made an attempt but it does not work at all, I don't know how to fix it. Apologies for my inexperience.

I wish to ignore the following extensions:
.x
.xy
.yx
.y
.jpg

**list1.txt**

```
text.x
example.xy
file.yx
data.y
edit
edit.jpg
```

**list2.txt**

```
text
rainbow.z
file
data.y
sunshine
edit.test.jpg
edit.random
```

**result.txt**

```
rainbow.z
sunshine
edit.test.jpg
edit.random
```

My try:

```
while read LINE
    do
    line2=$LINE
    sed -i 's/\.x$//g' $LINE $line2
    sed -i 's/\.xy$//g' $LINE $line2
    sed -i 's/\.yx$//g' $LINE $line2
    sed -i 's/\.y$//g' $LINE $line2 
    then sed -i -e '$line' result.txt;
    fi
done < list2.txt
```

Edit: I forgot two requirements. The filenames can have . in them and not all filenames must have an extension. I know the extensions that must be ignored. I ammended the lists accordingly.

Comment: If extensions are to be ignored then why is `edit.png` in the result? (file1.txt already contains `edit` and `edit.jpg`)

Comment: Since my files can have "." in them and not all must have a file extension, I assume I must filter for specific file extensions. .png in my example is part of the filename. Would it be clearer if I use something else than png?

Comment: I don't think I understand the requirements entirely. Do you want to ignore only specific extensions? Then you must specify those extensions in the question.

Comment: You're right. I added the file extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `awk` solution might be more efficient for this task:

```
awk '
              { f=$0; sub(/\.(xy?|yx?|jpg)$/,"",f) }
    NR==FNR   { a[f]; next }
    !(f in a)
' list1.txt list2.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem I posed initially but unfortunately not my real task. I realized I forgot two requirements and added them in an edit.

Comment: @JohnFreeman1212 I've modified the code. It gives the expected output now.

Comment: Works, I accepted this as the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`comm` can do precisely this.

You can preprocess the input:

- strip the suffices
- sort (`comm` expects sorted input)
- remove duplicates

```
ss()( sed 's/\.\(x\|xy\|yx\|y\|jpg\)$//' "$@" | sort -u )

comm -13 <(ss list1.txt) <(ss list2.txt) >result.txt
```

---

Your code was:

```
while read LINE
    do
    line2=$LINE
    sed -i 's/\.x$//g' $LINE $line2
    sed -i 's/\.xy$//g' $LINE $line2
    sed -i 's/\.yx$//g' $LINE $line2
    sed -i 's/\.y$//g' $LINE $line2 
    then sed -i -e '$line' result.txt;
    fi
done < list2.txt
```

Some issues that immediately jump out:

1. syntax error - `then`/`fi` but no matching `if`
2. you never access `list1`
3. you don't quote variables when you use them, so whitespace and special characters will cause problems
4. `while read ... sed ... sed ... sed ...` is inefficient - multiple invocations of sed instead of just one, and a loop that sed would perform implicitly
5. `sed` expects file arguments not strings
6. `sed -i` will try to overwrite input file arguments
7. you use `result.txt` as both input and output to sed but never assign any contents to it
8. you try to use data (`$line`) as sed commands, instead of applying sed commands to that data
9. because you used single-quotes, `sed -i -e '$line'` will attempt to run a (non-existent) sed command `line` on the last line of input (`$`)
10. `g` option to `s///` does nothing when search is anchored

Comment: Thank you, the first line works, but I get the error "sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unterminated `s' command" for the second line. Also unfortunately I left out two additional requirements that I have, I added them to the post.

Comment: @JohnFreeman1212 there was a typo. try the edited version (`s/...` -> `s/...//`)

Comment: It runs, but I get edit.test instead of edit.test.jpg with this.

Comment: The awk solution is better if you want the original line instead of the line with the extension ignored, although it may fail if input does not fit in memory.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `join`:

```bash
$ join -t. -j1 -v2 -o 2.1,2.2 <(sort list1.txt) <(sort list2.txt) | sed 's/\.$//'
rainbow.z
sunshine
```

(The bit of `sed` is needed to turn `sunshine.` into `sunshine`)

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem I posed initially but unfortunately not my real task. I realized I forgot two requirements and added them in an edit.